# 'viewDidLoad' not declared in NSViewController?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm a cocoa and Objective-c newbie. 
I'm trying to build a mac app, and when I try to create a new controller which inherits from NSViewController, it automatically gives me a `- (void)viewDidLoad` in the .m file (but not in the .h). The problem is that the compiler always yells saying "No visible @interface for 'NSViewContoller' declares the selector 'viewDidLoad'.

How is this possible? Please help me understand what is happening here and how I can fix it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewDidLoad is only supported in NSViewController if you target OSX Yosemite and upwards ! Remove it if you are targeting below Yosemite for your app and use `-awakeFromNib` or `-loadView` method instead.

As you can see it in [Apple's NSViewController Reference](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/viewDidLoad) 
that it is

`Available in OS X v10.10 and later.`

P.S This happened to me while developing an app for OSX Mevericks and above when I inherited a class from NSViewController and Xcode 6 automatically generated ViewDidLoad method for me which is actually a bug (I Think)

Comment: see: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174952/backward-compatibility-of-xcode-osx/30196972#30196972>

Answer (score -2):

From documentation of apple, method `NSViewDidLoad`:

> "For a view controller originating in a nib file, this method is
>   called immediately after the view property is set. For a view
>   controller created programmatically, this method is called immediately
>   after the loadView method completes."

You need create a method in .h for view in your app.