# Backward compatibility of Xcode OSX

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, osx-mountain-lion, nsview, nsviewcontroller

How to use features such as `viewDidLoad` or `appDidBecomeActive` in Xcode 4.6.1 for OSX 10.8, which are available only for OSX 10.10 and above. Please suggest the alternative ways to use these functions.

Comment: I don't expect you can do this. You have quite an outdated version of Xcode.

Comment: Rather than implementing an override of `-viewDidLoad`, just override `-loadView`. Call through to `super` and then put any additional code after that. That's effectively "view-did-load" code. As to `appDidBecomeActive`, that doesn't seem to be part of any Cocoa API. Where did you find that?

Comment: You can only use what is available through the supported SDK.

Comment: When you say `appDidBecomeActive`, do you mean `applicationDidBecomeActive:`?  That has been part of OS X since 10.0.

Comment: @JWWalker : ya thats what i mean applicationDidBecomeActive is what am talking about ....

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Ken Thomas's comment; this is the code that I use:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // if we're running on 10.8 or older…
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
        [self viewDidLoad]; // call viewDidLoad (added in 10.9)
    }
}

//
// This will be called by loadView pre-10.9; directly otherwise
//
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // --- YOUR CODE HERE ---
}   // viewDidLoad
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there any reason to call `[super viewDidLoad];` from a derived class?

Comment: It would depend on if the super class implements a viewDidLoad method. To be paranoid, you could use instancesRespondToSelector on the superclass to determine if it's implemented there. Note: sending respondsToSelector: to super is equivalent to sending it to self. Instead, you must invoke the NSObject class method instancesRespondToSelector: You cannot simply use [[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] since this may cause the method to fail if it is invoked by a subclass.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_9` as the header indicates `viewDidLoad` wasn't added until 10.10.

Comment: Alternatively the explicit version check could be replaced by `if (![NSViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(viewDidLoad)])…`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd override setView

```
@interface MyViewController : NSViewController 
@end

@implementation MyViewController 
- (void)setView:(NSView*)v {
    super.view = v;
    // if we're running on 10.8 or older…
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
        [self viewDidLoad]; // call viewDidLoad (added in 10.9)
    }
}
@end
```