# How do views load on OSX 10.9?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I've only been developing on OSX 10.10+, I'm want my application to work on both 10.9 and 10.10+. I'm having the issue of viewDidLoad() is only available on 10.10+. How can I flexible views and view controllers to work on both?

From looking at the source code it looks like I need to override init? But when overriding init:nibName:nibBundleOrNil: but it also requires init:coder and that doesn't make much sense to me (it's undocumented in the source).

Comment: Would overloading `loadView` do the trick? You could also try adding a `didSet` for the view property, but that's straying into undocumented behaviour given that it's a read-only property.

Answer (score 1):

Before 10.10 the NSViewController was basically doing nothing (it was the NSWindowController doing most of the job) ;) On 10.10 it gained the methods similar from iOS world (viewDidLoad...) and one really important thing, it was finally put automatically into NSResponder chain (NSApp sendAction:... will check if the viewController has the method).

So how to get the functionality?

1. use awakeFromNib
2. manually add view into responder chain (if you compile with 10.10 SDK then the view is added automatically on 10.10 and later; if you compile with 10.9 SDK you have to add it manually)
3. use XIBs; you can't use storyboards -> they use 10.10 nsviewcontrollers -> dead end

So if you use storyboards it's a lot of work. If you don't have clean MVC/MVVM architecture then it's not worth.

Alternative is to double your classes pre10.10 and after10.10 but this means having the same code layed off twice (once using storyboards, once using XIBs).

EDIT:

As @geowar suggested you can override loadView. Mind that you still can't use storyboards and you have to manually add your viewController into responderChain

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // if we're running on 10.8 or older…
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
        [self viewDidLoad]; // call viewDidLoad (added in 10.9)
    }
}
```

Alternatively

```
- (void)setView:(NSView*)view {
    super.view = view;
    // if we're running on 10.8 or older…
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
        [self viewDidLoad]; // call viewDidLoad (added in 10.9)
    }
}
@end
```

EDIT2:

awakeFromNib is called after loadView (which gets the new view from xib and instantiates it). As suggested by @Daij-Djan another solution is to override setter.

> Advice for People who Are Looking for -viewWillLoad and -viewDidLoad
>   Methods in NSViewController
>
> Even though NSWindowController has -windowWillLoad and -windowDidLoad
>   methods for you to override the NSViewController class introduced in
>   Mac OS 10.5 does not have corresponding -viewWillLoad and -viewDidLoad
>   methods. You can override -[NSViewController loadView] to customize
>   what happens immediately before or immediately after nib loading done
>   by a view controller.

[image]

Comment: see: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174952/backward-compatibility-of-xcode-osx/30196972#30196972>

Comment: Thanks. I add it to my answer. Storyboards can't be used and the responder chain works as I described.

Comment: this is wrong - you can use whatever you like - for a xib awakeFromNib is called after the view is there.. this is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

to have thee equivalent of 10.10 on 10.9 write a VC like this

```
@interface MyViewController : NSViewController 
@end

@implementation MyViewController 
- (void)setView:(NSView*)v {
    super.view = v;
    // if we're running on 10.8 or older…
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8) {
        [self viewDidLoad]; // call viewDidLoad (added in 10.9)
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You are correct but you can't call this equivalent. You can't get the same functionality of NSViewController behaviour just by doing this. Especially if he uses storyboard which is a dead end for 10.9.

Comment: why? if that doesn't suffice, he can even go and override awakeFromNib if setView isn't called. don't get it :)

Comment: In 97 percent cases it's enough and you are 100 percent correct ;)